# Operator Norm Inequality

Tags: matrices, inequality

If $U$ and $V$ are unitary $n \times n$ matrices, show that the commutator $[U,V] := U V U^{-1} V^{-1}$ obeys the inequality

$\displaystyle  \| [U,V] - I \|_{op} \leq 2 \| U - I \|_{op} \| V - I \|_{op}$

I was having a great deal of trouble with this and I suspect there is a simple solution. The hint is to control $\| UV - VU \|_{op}$. (op indicates the operator norm everywhere.)

Comment: To execute the hint expand $(U-I)(V-I)-(V-I)(U-I) , take norms on both sides, and apply the triangle inequality. To apply the hint use the fact that unitary matrices and their inverses have operator norm 1. Edit: noticed that someone alreadyt answered exactly these steps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following identities:

1. $UV U^{-1}V^{-1} = (UV -VU)U^{-1}V^{-1}$.
2. $UV -VU= (U-I)(V-I) -(V-I)(U-I)$.